# Solr query to find a document's string field matches a string > 70%

Tags: solr, string-matching, similarity

I am stuck on a problem.
Here is an example of doc and I want those docs where address field's matching percentage is greater than 75%.
I need document matching which match with a search string greater than 75%.

```
{    
     "id":1,
     "address": "Location 1, state 1 , country 1"
},
{    
     "id":2,
     "address": "Location 2, state 2 , country 2"
},
{    
     "id":3,
     "address": "Location 3, state 1 , country 1"
}

address:"state+1+country+1"
```

i need document having id 1 and 3.

Comment: can you show us hows your schema look like? how are you indexing documents ?

Comment: What is 75% here? Usually percentages apply to how much of a *query* matches. But in your case, it seems opposite. What if user enters just "state 2"?